# How to check out a Subversion repository using svn+ssh protocol?

Tags: svn, ssh

I'm trying to checkout a repository via command line (the 'svn co' command), using the svn+ssh protocol. I need to checkout as a different user than what I currently am. The command `svn co svn+ssh://username@server/repo/` would make sense, however when it prompts for a password, it never accepts it.

How do I checkout a repository over svn+ssh with a different user?

Edit to clarify a concern that this is off topic:
I'm trying to create a script to update a website to the current version. This is where the script fails.

Comment: this is something for your sysadmin to figure out

Comment: davethegr8: that still doesn't make this a programming question.

Comment: what you are trying to do works for everybody else, so if you are going to waste our time, at least post some relevant lines from the log file, or _something_ we could use to find the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You might be confusing your SVN user name with your account name: svn+ssh is to be used only when you have a real account on the server that contains the repository.  Is it the case?  Can you log in with ssh on that server?  If so, it probably is a configuration problem on the server.

On the other hand, if your problem is that your current user name is (say) dave, and that your SVN user name is david, then you shouldn't use svn+ssh; just use the standard svn protocol, type Enter once when prompted for the password (SVN will ignore it).  Then SVN will ask you for the user name: type david, and then the password when prompted.

Comment: Yes, ssh access to the server is fine.

No, I can't use the svn protocol. The server rejects those connections. No, I can't allow that. All svn access MUST be through ssh.

Comment: OK, so that's not what I thought at first.  What are the versions of the SVN on each side?  I recently had repeated problems with SVN client version 1.5 talking to 1.4 servers.  The only way I could fix it was by downgrading ...

Comment: The server version is 1.2 or similar. I don't know what the client version is, but it can't be higher than that.

Comment: Well, then I'm out of idea for this one.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Well, here is the solution.

The subversion server asks for a password multiple times. That seems silly to me, but that's SVN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
svn checkout svn+ssh://your.remote-server.com/home/svn/test
```